# Android - Runtime exception. "Unable to instantiate receiver"

Tags: android, package

I am having this error after I tidy up my codes into different subpackage name.

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5879): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver sg.pms.ConnectivityHandler: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sg.pms.ConnectivityHandler in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/sg.pms-1.apk]
```

An activity (in the main package) which will execute this code.

```
package sg.pms;
...
...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Register a timer to trigger ConnectivityHandler task every 10minutes
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectivityHandler.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
            234324243, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, 0, 60 * 1000,
            pendingIntent);
}
```

ConnectivityHandler class in a subpackage.

```
package sg.pms.connectivity;
...
public class ConnectivityHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ...
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

EDIT:
Seems like it may be a bug in Eclipse. I perform a cleanup of the project space and do a build again and it solves this "mislink" problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ClassNotFoundException: ConnectivityHandler is giving you the details of the issue.

> sg.pms.ConnectivityHandler

Are you sure this ConnectivityHandler is still in this package?

It looks to be in

> sg.pms.connectivity

Comment: when I mouse over the class in this piece of code Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectivityHandler.class); it is refering to the correct package which is "sg.pms.connectivity" But I am not sure why when running it is refering to package "sg.pms"